# How can stop text wrapping around some floated divs?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I floated 3 images in `div`s in the middle of a long section of text. I want to float them so the site keeps it's 'liquid' design, adapting to any width browser window. But if text starts wrapping to the left of them on wide Windows, it looks bad. I'd like them to float, but still be able to clear text around them so they look like a block element. How can I do that?

I thought maybe of sticking in a 100% width `div` right after the image `div`s, that's 1px high, and filled with a 1px image that's just the background color. Will that work?

http://www.briligg.com/frailty.html
The images in question are the ones at the beginning of the 'the cause of addiction is stress' section. Line 134 to 146, references the internal style sheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a `clear: left` on your section of text following the images.

That appears to be your `div` with class `text` though I don't know if you would want to universally apply the `clear` to all the divs with that class.

Comment: but for some reason the third image ignores the left margin of the parent div.text when i narrow the window... um, do you see why?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "ignores the left margin." The `div.text` is NOT the parent of the final floated image based on my analysis of your page. It appears you close your `div` around the first two images, but missed the third.