# Wrapping longer table under adjacent, shorter table

Tags: html, css

Per the following screenshot, I have two `<div>` elements, each containing tables, with those `<div>` placed adjacent to one another.  Additionally, the `<body>` content is placed ***below*** those `<div>`.

How can I wrap the left table under the right one, if the there is unused space under the right table?

[image]

```html
<head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Adjacent table wrapping</title>

  <style>
    table {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 0.0rem 0.25rem 0.0rem 0.5rem;
    }
      
    table tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #edf0f0; }

    #left_div {
      float: left;
      wrap:inline;
      width: 60%;
    }

    #left_div table td:first-child {
    }

    #right_div {
      float: right;
      clear: right;
      width: 39%;
    }

    /* Without the following, "clear: left;", if there was space between the
     * "left_div" and the "right_div", then the body text was wrapping between
     * those adjacent (float {left | right}) <div>. The solution, per
     *   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258944/how-can-stop-text-wrapping-around-some-floated-divs
     * was to add
     *   <div id="clear_left"></div>
     * which enables text to both flow below the "left_div", and also to the left
     * of the "right_div".
     */

    #clear_left {
      clear: left;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- LEFT DIV -->
  <div id="left_div">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>URL</td>
        <td>example.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Source</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>2021</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Modified</td>
        <td>July 01, 2021</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Comment</td>
        <td> Suspendisse efficitur pulvinar elementum.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Key points</td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li class="body">Vestibulum a est eu erat rutrum scelerisque non et diam.</li>
            <li class="body">Nam ut fringilla enim.</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Notes</td>
        <td>Pellentesque finibus mauris vel nulla euismod mollis. Nunc sit amet euismod purus, ut viverra neque.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>More notes</td>
        <td>Quisque eget ante efficitur, dignissim felis nec, tempor dolor. Curabitur elementum dui et odio pharetra varius. Phasellus molestie ullamcorper nulla. Morbi finibus nisi a consequat mollis. Etiam in sagittis sapien, sit amet commodo augue.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <meta name="summary" content="" />
        <td>Summary</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse efficitur pulvinar elementum. Vestibulum a est eu erat rutrum scelerisque non et diam. Nam ut fringilla enim. Pellentesque finibus mauris vel nulla euismod mollis. Nunc sit amet euismod purus, ut viverra neque. Quisque eget ante efficitur, dignissim felis nec, tempor dolor. Curabitur elementum dui et odio pharetra varius. Phasellus molestie ullamcorper nulla. Morbi finibus nisi a consequat mollis. Etiam in sagittis sapien, sit amet commodo augue.</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- RIGHT DIV -->
  <div id="right_div">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <b><center>Flag of Canada</center></b>
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Canada_%28Pantone%29.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Canada_%28Pantone%29.svg.png" alt="Flag of Canada" width="400"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- Prevent <body> content between "left_div" and "right_div": -->
  <div id="clear_left"></div>
  <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

  <h2>Content</h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse efficitur pulvinar elementum. Vestibulum a est eu erat rutrum scelerisque non et diam. Nam ut fringilla enim. Pellentesque finibus mauris vel nulla euismod mollis. Nunc sit amet euismod purus, ut viverra neque. Quisque eget ante efficitur, dignissim felis nec, tempor dolor. Curabitur elementum dui et odio pharetra varius. Phasellus molestie ullamcorper nulla. Morbi finibus nisi a consequat mollis. Etiam in sagittis sapien, sit amet commodo augue.</p>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Truly dynamically sized L-shaped tables are (at this time) impossible to achieve.

[Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389889/non-rectangular-css-grid-elements) might support it in the future.

Until then, you have to compromise on some level.
If you can reasonably estimate the size of the image and the size of first couple or rows then [rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables) might be a good solution, having the image span the length of the first couple of rows.

Or if your content allows for it, you could mimic a table like behavior in css, and have the image `float:right` alongside it.

```css
.table {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.table div.row {
  padding: 0.0rem 0.25rem 0.0rem 0.5rem;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.table div.row span {}

.table div.row span:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.table div.row span:last-child {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.table div.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #edf0f0;
}

.right_div {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.flag {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #edf0f0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- LEFT DIV -->
<div id="left_div">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="right_div">
      <div class="flag">
        <b><center>Flag of Canada</center></b>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Canada_%28Pantone%29.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Canada_%28Pantone%29.svg.png" alt="Flag of Canada" width="340" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span>URL</span>
      <span>example.com</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Source</span>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Year</span>
      <span>2021</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Modified</span>
      <span>July 01, 2021</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Comment</span>
      <span> Suspendisse efficitur pulvinar elementum.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Key points</span>
      <span>
          <ul>
            <li class="body">Vestibulum a est eu erat rudivum scelerisque non et diam.</li>
            <li class="body">Nam ut fringilla enim.</li>
          </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span>Notes</span>
      <span>Pellentesque finibus mauris vel nulla euismod mollis. Nunc sit amet euismod purus, ut viverra neque.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>More notes</span>
      <span>Quisque eget ante efficitur, dignissim felis nec, tempor dolor. Curabitur elementum dui et odio pharediva varius. Phasellus molestie ullamcorper nulla. Morbi finibus nisi a consequat mollis. Etiam in sagittis sapien, sit amet commodo augue.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <span>Summary</span>
      <meta name="summary" content="" />
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse efficitur pulvinar elementum. Vestibulum a est eu erat rudivum scelerisque non et diam. Nam ut fringilla enim. Pellentesque finibus mauris vel nulla euismod mollis. Nunc sit amet euismod purus, ut viverra neque. Quisque eget ante efficitur, dignissim felis nec, tempor dolor. Curabitur elementum dui et odio pharediva varius. Phasellus molestie ullamcorper nulla. Morbi finibus nisi a consequat mollis. Etiam in sagittis sapien, sit amet commodo augue.</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```